# POST fails after second callback

Tags: android, post, retrofit

From my Android App, the first time I call to my RestAdapater API with retrofit it executes correctly but if I try to do this again I get a the following error:

> error retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

Moreover, if I run the app again or wait some time this problem doesn't happen..the first time.
It seems like I have to clear some kind of cache data of this callback.

My API:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
@POST("/androidDevelopment/AppComercialesCat/WSIngresarCliente.php")
public void ingresarNuevoCliente(@Field("clienteID") int uclienteId,@Field("clienteNom") String uclienteNom,@Field("clienteEmail") String uclienteEmail,
                                 @Field("clienteMov") String uclienteMov,@Field("clienteTel") String uclienteTel,@Field("nombreTienda") String unombreTienda,
                                 @Field("contacto") String contacto,@Field("empresaNIF") String uempresaNif,@Field("Impuestos") String uImpuestos,@Field("empresaDireccion") String uempresaDireccion,
                                 @Field("empresaProvincia") String uempresaProvincia,@Field("empresaPoblacion") String uempresaPoblacion,@Field("empresaCP") String uempresaCP,
                                 @Field("empresaCtaBancaria") String uempresaCtaBancaria,@Field("empresaCatacroquer") String uempresaCatacroquer,@Field("usuarioID") int uUsuarioId,
                                 Callback<Clientes> response);
```

---

Api's call:

```
ClientesAPI api = restAdapter.create(ClientesAPI.class);
            api.ingresarNuevoCliente(mclienteId, mNombre, mEmail, mMovil, mTel, mTienda,
                    mContacto, mNIF, mImp,mDir, mProv, mPobl, mCP, mCta, mObs, userId,
                    new Callback<Clientes>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Clientes clientes, Response response) {
                            //Intent goToMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Intro.class);
                            //startActivity(goToMain);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "error " + error.toString());
                            Log.v(TAG, "error " + error.getResponse().getStatus());
                            Log.v(TAG, "error " + error.getResponse().getReason());
                            Log.v(TAG, "error " + error.getResponse().getBody());
                            Log.v(TAG, "error " + error.getCause());
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
        }
    };
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is a retrofit rookie question.

Comment: you are receiving response but the parameters in Clients class didn't match with response for decoding json just check it again and you will get it.

Comment: Mahesh Giri, first time I receive this works perfect. The problem is in the consequent requests. So it's not a problema about how to decode de json.